# Algebraic independence of polynomials vs their principal homogeneous parts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $P_1,...,P_m\in F[x_1,...,x_n]$ be polynomials of $n$  variables with principal homogeneous parts $p_1,...,p_m\in F[x_1,...,x_n]$. What is the relation between algebraic independence of $P_1,...,P_m$  and that of $p_1,...,p_m$? Does any one imply the other?

My understanding is that if $m>n$ both  are dependent, because the homomorphism
$$
F[x_1,...,x_n,...,x_m]\to F[P_1,...,P_m]\subset F[x_1,...,x_n]
$$
cannot be injective. I am especially interested in the case $m=n$ and $F\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$. Thank you.

P.S. I think this is related to the question of whether the spectral variety of a completely integrable system in  the algebraic geometry sense (which is based on the independence of the principal symbols) is in fact a hyperplane.

Comment: By the principal homogeneous part of a polynomial do you mean its homogeneous part of highest degree?

Comment: Exactly. In  PDE this is called the principal symbol, hence the terminology.

Comment: Here is an off-the-cuff remark. $P_i$ algebraically independent does not mean $p_i$s are. For an easy example, take $P_1=x+x^2, P_2=y+x^2$, in two variables.

Comment: I think you could upvote and accept @Mohan answer which is clear and elementary. An alternative approach can be based on the Jacobian criterion for algebraic independence. Mohan's answer follows immediately from this criterion, but it's a bigger gun than necessary.

Comment: Of course, I should and I did. But who cares if nobody thinks my question is interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the remark, $P_i$ algebraically independent does not mean $p_i$ are.

Conversely, if $P_i$ are algebraically dependent, so are the $p_i$s. For this, let $F(t_1,\ldots, t_m)\neq 0$ be a polynomial with $F(P_1,\ldots, P_m)=0$. Let $Q_i(z,x)$ be the homogenization of $P_i(x)$ with $\deg P_i=\deg Q_i$, so that $Q_i(0,x)=p_i(x)$. Then, you can find a polynomial $G(z,t)$ with $G(1,t)=F(t)$ and $z$ not dividing $G$. Further, $G(z,Q_1,\ldots, Q_m)$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $z,x$. When we put $z=1$, we simply get $F(P_i)=0$ and thus $G(z,Q_i)=0$. Then we have $G(0,t)\neq 0$ and $G(0, p_i)=0$, since this is just putting $z=0$ in $0=G(z,Q_i)$.

Comment: Isn't quite clear how you chosen the polynomial $G$. For instance, I think you need more than "$G(1,t)=F(t)$ and $z$ not dividing $G$" in order to conclude that "$G(z,Q_1,\ldots, Q_m)$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $z,x$".

Comment: @user26857 Let $\deg P_i=d_i$ and write $F(t)=\sum a_{\alpha}t^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is a multiindex and no $a_{\alpha}=0$. Let $d$ be the maximum of $\alpha\cdot (d_1,\ldots, d_m)$. Let $G(z,t)=a_{\alpha} z^{d-\alpha\cdot (d_1,\ldots, d_m)} t^{\alpha}$. Then $G(1,t)=F(t)$, $z$ does not divide $G(z,t)$ and $G(z, Q_1,\ldots, Q_m)$ is homogeneous in $z, x$ of degree $d$.

Comment: Now everything looks fine. (I suppose $\alpha(d_1,\dots,d_m)=\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_id_i$.) I've thought about the choice of $G$ by grading $F[z,t_1,\dots,t_m]$ with $\deg z=1$ and $\deg t_i=d_i$, but I suppose it's more or less the same thing you did.